# CSS Transition Nav Bar - how to keep effect when on page

Tags: html, css, transition, nav

I have a transition nav bar that i made by following this tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wwe2zOz030o). However, what i want is to keep the effect when im on the page i clicked, for example. the Home nav will stay expanded when im looking at the page, but i want to keep the effect of the transitions of the other menu items... so if i am on the HOME page then the Home button will stay expanded whether i hover on it or not, but if i was to hover over another menu item then that one would expand and reduce the size of the home button so it always fill the same amount of space.

I hope this makes sense... here is the link to my coding http://jsfiddle.net/h0fe2txL/

thanks in advance for your help!

```
</style>
</head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker' rel='stylesheet'    type='text/css'>
<body>
<div id="container">
<a href="#"><div class="menu">
<p class="p1">HOME</p>
<p class="p2">THIS IS OUR INTRO  </p>
</div>
</a>

<a href="#"><div class="menu1">
<p class="p1">GALLERY</p>
<p class="p2">THIS IS MY GALLERY</p>
</div>
</a>

<a href="#"><div class="menu2">
<p class="p1">PROJECTS</p>
<p class="p2">MY ART COLLECTION</p>
</div>
</a>

<a href="#"><div class="menu3">
<p class="p1">CONTACT</p>
<p class="p2">CONTACT ME</p>
</div>
</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code --

```
a{text-decoration:none;
}

body{
}

#container{
height: 125px;
width: 915px;
background-color: transparent;
position: relative;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
border: medium dashed rgba(0,0,0,1);
}   
.menu{
height: 125px;
width: 150px;
background-color:rgba(204,0,51,1);
float: left;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
text-decoration: none;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.menu1{
height: 125px;
width: 150px;
background-color:rgba(0,102,51,1);
float: left;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.menu2{
height: 125px;
width: 150px;
background-color:rgba(0,102,153,1);
float: left;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.menu3{
height: 125px;
width: 150px;
background-color:rgba(255,102,51,1);
float: left;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.p1{
font-family: "Permanent Marker", cursive;
font-size: 25px;
color: rgba(228,228,228,1);
font-weight: bold;
position: relative;
width: 100px;
top: 0px;
left: 7px;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
text-align: center;
}
.p2{
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 11px;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.menu:hover{
width:450px;
 }
 .menu1:hover{
width:450px;
}
.menu2:hover{
width:450px;
}
.menu3:hover{
width:450px;
}

.menu:hover .p1{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.menu:hover .p2{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.menu1:hover .p1{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
 }
.menu1:hover .p2{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.menu2:hover .p1{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.menu2:hover .p2{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.menu3:hover .p1{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
 }
.menu3:hover .p2{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

Comment: Add a class `active` to the `:hover` selectors. For example, `.menu1:hover` would be `.menu1:hover, .menu1.active`. The class you provide over php.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, however i wondered if you could provide a little more detail, i tried what you suggested but it doesnt seem to work, it just makes the menu1 stay at 150px when i want it to stay at 450px but if i was to hover over menu2 than menu1 would shrink to allow space for menu2 to enlarge and fill the space of the container.

Comment: I made this update for you. Forgot that the class must be removed. http://jsfiddle.net/L8t2v03b/1/ (notice this isn't final and still a bit quirky). I used jQuery just because of the selector.

Comment: this is brilliant - thanks - it fills the whole container. however, forgive me, i am a newbie, but when i hover across the other menu items everything is pushed down the page when i just want that active one to shrink when i have hovered over another one to enlarge. thanks for all your help!

Comment: That is exactly why I said it was quirky. The only way to change it would be to somehow freeze the css transition using javascript, remove the `active` class and resume the transition. But I have never heard of freezing transitions...